# Continuous independent variables that sum up to 100%

Tags: regression, compositional-data

As I am studying the capital structure of firms, the total of proportions owned by different ownership types (free float, institutional ownership ... etc.) will be 100% of the company shares. In my study each of those ownership types is an independent variable. Hence, when running regressions, one of these variables will be dropped due to collinearity.

Is there any transformations that can be done to these variables in order to have all of them in the model? If not, which variable (highest/ lowest correlated with the dependent variable) is to be dropped?

Comment: So the "scientific term" is compositional data. As you correctly identified one variable will always be explained by the others.  While you can simply drop one it is not recommend, especially if you have many variables summing up to 100%. So I read up on compositional data analysis. In the context of microbiome data this is often used. So maybe there will be more literature  on the topic. Unfortunately I myself do not know enough about the topic.

Comment: If you remove the intercept from the model, the design matrix will be full rank.

Comment: Why is dropping a variable a problem?

Comment: The dropped variate is not *collinear* insofar as it is a *linear combination* of the others.  Noah's suggestion is one possibility. Another option is to use a qualitative, ANOVA-type categorical factor for ownership. The resulting parameters and t-statistics will be quite informative.

Answer (score 2):

A "traditional" transformation for $n$ variables that must add up to a constant (usually we use 1 corresponding to 100%), is to work with $n-1$ parameters $\alpha_i \in (-\infty, \infty)$, to define the $n$th one as $\alpha_n = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$ ("sum to zero constraint") and to use the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) to define
$$w_i = \frac{e^{\alpha_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\alpha_i}}.$$

We will then have $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i =1$ and all $w_i$ will be in $(0,1)$.

The $\alpha_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ could then each have a set of linear regression terms behind them (or some other kind of model, e.g. if you like a neural network or whatever else).

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a possible approach.   Suppose you have independent variables $x_i,y_i,z_i$ with $x_i+y_i+z_i=1$ and you are trying to predict the dependent variable $w_i$ by linear regression.

Drop one of the independent variables (perhaps the $x_i$s, and I would choose the one with the greatest variance) and get a result of the form $\hat w_i=\beta_0+\beta_y y_i+\beta_z z_i$

You could use this directly, or you could reintroduce $x_i$ so the coefficients of the independent variables add up to something, and I would choose $0$, so of the form  $\hat w_i=\gamma_0+\gamma_x x_i+\gamma_y y_i+\gamma_z z_i$  where

- $\gamma_x = \frac13(1-\beta_y-\beta_z)$
- $\gamma_y =\beta_y+\gamma_x$
- $\gamma_z =\beta_z+\gamma_x$
- $\gamma_0 =\beta_0-\gamma_x$

You would than have to be careful interpreting $\hat w_i=\gamma_0+\gamma_x x_i+\gamma_y y_i+\gamma_z z_i$, but the way to read it is to say that, for example, an increase in $y$ and equal reduction in $z$ has an effect on $\hat w$ of $(\gamma_y-\gamma_z)$ times the size of the change